# Single Section Branch Line Coupler at 73 GHz

Tags: rf, microwave, microstrip, coupler

SE,

I am having trouble making sense of my simulation charts for a branch-line coupler tuned to
73.5 GHz.
I followed Keysight's tutorial given by the link below.

https://www.keysight.com/us/en/assets/7018-05295/technical-overviews/5992-1629.pdf

I finished this correctly and started using this template for my own. However I did change the substrate parameters to Rogers 5880 as seen in the schematic.

[image: ADS Schematic of Coupler]
Figure 1: Schematic

However, I cannot replicate the (theoretical) 3dB insertion loss and 90 degrees phase shift.
I am getting -200 dB loss (pretty much all the power) and a fluctuation in phase and I don't know where I am going wrong. All the components are right for the theoretical model.
I read somewhere since the width of the microstrip is much larger than the length then the coupling is thrown off.

If that is the case, then is a microstrip branch-line coupler at this frequency possible to design?

[image]
Figure 2: Simulations of S21, S31, S41 and Phase

Comment: nice 200 dB pad. is it connected? shorted?

Comment: Yah those won't work at that wavelngth

Comment: That breaks my heart to hear but it had to be done :(

Comment: Try a thinner substrate with smaller trace width. Your trace width is huge relative to the wavelength!

Comment: Also, I always recommend trying with ideal transmission lines before setting up the microstrip model.